# Print the output in a table in any file(.doc/.xml/.xls) without having a separate package like xlwt

Tags: python, python-3.3, xlwt

I am new to programming and tried to write a python script for my work. It worked well. I need to print the output in an excel. Finally i was able to do it with xlwt. Here is the script.

```
def sh(dir):   
a = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = a.add_sheet('sheet1')
n = 0
for r,d,f in os.walk(dir):
    for files in f:
        if files.endswith(".xml"):
            print files
            dom=parse(os.path.join(r, files))
            name = dom.getElementsByTagName('rev')
            title = dom.getElementsByTagName('title')
            sheet.write(n, 0, files)
            sheet.write(n, 1, title[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
            sheet.write(n, 2, name[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
            n += 1
            print title[0].firstChild.nodeValue
            print name[0].firstChild.nodeValue
a.save('sha.xls')
```

Now the problem is I work in the files in CITRIX server. The admin doesn't know how to add the package to python installed in our server. I tried raising many tickets, but failed in all. Now i gotta do all the work with the standard package with python 3.3. I need a solution now. How i can print the output in a table format without having any package?

e.g. the output will be

```
1_1543-CRA 119 1364_2.xml   Router Processor Card      A1
```

IS there a way to do this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. In the print statement, i included this statement  "sep='\t'" and exported the output to csv.

e.g.

print (files, title[0].firstChild.nodeValue, name[0].firstChild.nodeValue, sep='\t')